# C# BigInteger.ModPow bug?

Tags: c#, java, .net, biginteger

I'm using the .NET [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268287.aspx) class to perform some math operations. However the [ModPow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.modpow.aspx) method is giving me the wrong results. I have compared it to Java which I think is correct:

```
// C#
var a = new BigInteger(-1);
var b = new BigInteger(3);
var c = new BigInteger(5);
var x = BigInteger.ModPow(a, b, c); // (x = -1)

// Java
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("-1");
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("3");
BigInteger c = new BigInteger("5");
BigInteger x = a.modPow(b, c); // (x = 4)
```

Is it a bug in the .NET class or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The name is misleading; it's not the modulus operator in the first place. It's the remainder operator. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just a matter of definitions.  From [MSDN on C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.op_modulus.aspx):

> The sign of the value returned by the modulus operation depends on the sign of dividend: If dividend is positive, the modulus operation returns a positive result; if it is negative, the modulus operation returns a negative result. The behavior of the modulus operation with `BigInteger` values is identical to the modulus operation with other integral types.

And from [the JavaDocs for `mod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#mod%28java.math.BigInteger%29):

> This method differs from `remainder` in that it always returns a non-negative `BigInteger`.

For more info, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation.